# Calculating performance decay of a strategy

Tags: equities, quant-trading-strategies, trading, risk-management, statistics

Came across this thread which basically advises t-test for difference in means across periods to calculate whether our edge is deteriorating.  The catch being that this test will probably not be accurate for most lower frequency strategies.

[How to compute the alpha decay of a strategy?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2412/how-to-compute-the-alpha-decay-of-a-strategy)

What other methods can we use to test for loss of edge btwn periods?  Are some more robust to sample size than others?